# Heatmap using ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

My Data looks like this:

```
data1 <- read.table(text = "District    Block   IE       FE     AOE     CLE      CS
A             A1    4.87    17.54   13.85   9.01    45.27
                 B             B1    8.19    20.83   14.59   7.04    50.65
                 C             C1    8.71    19.16   16.54   8.24    52.65
                 D             D1    2.43    11.77   11.51   6.96    32.67
                 E             E1    6.85    13.54   14.54   5.7     40.63
                 F             F1    7.02    19.96   13.96   3.82    44.76
                 G             G1    2.55    11.64   8.74    5.06    27.99
                 H             H1    9.81    20.2    12.62   5.95    48.58
                 I             I1    6.56    15.49   12.32   8.08    42.45
                 J             J1    9.47    22.86   25      22.73   80.06
                 K             K1    10.2    20.18   20.14   20.06   70.58
                 L             L1    9.52    14.86   16.95   18.23   59.56", header = TRUE)
```

I have created data matrix from the dataframe.My initial code looks like this

```
row.names(data1)<-data1$Column1

data1<-select(data1,-c(1))
data1<-data.matrix()
data1_heatmap<-heatmap(data1,Rowv = NA,Colv = NA,col=heat.colors(256),scale = "none",margins = c(12,3))
```

Whenever I am using the above code,it plots for the whole sheet.

I have 2 issues:

1. I need to show the cell values which are present in the data matrix.
2. Also i need to specify a color range in each column from IE to CS.For example,in IE column less the 4.87 is red,6.56 to 6.85 is orange and green for greater than 8.17.So basically user defined range for each column.

Comment: What does this have to do with `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with ggplot2 (starting with the original data1):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
row.names(data1)<-data1$Column1
data1<-select(data1,-c(1))
data1 <- melt(data1, id='Block')
data1$value <- cut(data1$value,breaks = c(-Inf,4.87, 6.56, 6.58, 8.17, 14, 19, 21, Inf),right = FALSE) # bin IE variable
ggplot(data =  data1, aes(x = Block, y = variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PRGn")
```

[image]